# TFS Merge conflict: Which source file encoding should I use?

Tags: visual-studio, character-encoding, merge

I am doing a merge from a feature branch and one of the conflicts is that the two files have different source file encodings. I get a resolution message like:

```
File encoding has changed. Please select an encoding for the file:
```

The two options I get are `Windows-125`2 and `utf-8` The file in question is an scss file. Which encoding should I choose and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, fix the conflict in a satisfactory way.

Second, use UTF-8 only. Windows-1252 is a legacy encoding and should be used only when necessary for compatibility reasons. SASS sources don't need it.

You should use UTF-8 because it is *de facto* standard for storing and transmitting text.